# Insert directive dynamically and compiling

Tags: angularjs

I have a scenario when a user click a link, I would like to insert a custom element into the DOM for example

```
    //user clicks    
    $scope.click = function () {
          var el = $compile("<my-directive></my-directive>")($scope);
          $element.after(el);
     };
```

The my-directive.... directive has an html template.. say for example (template1.html)

```
<p>My Template for my-directive</p>
{{SomeProperty}}
```

my-directive is defined like this

```
module.directive('myDirective', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/template1.html',
        scope: true
    };
}]);
```

If we assume the scope in myDirective  acutally has a value for SomeProperty after running this code I will indeed have the my-directive inserted into the DOM and replaced by the template - template1.html however the {{SomeProperty}} has not been replaced at all! How do I do this??

See [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Qnv6i8jhyRwMEWtRQO7?p=preview) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did `$compile("<my-directive></my-directive>")($scope.$parent);` in your Plunkr. Remove `.$parent`

Chenge template to:

```
<p>My Template for my-directive</p>
{{d.SomeProperty}}
```

As you did `d in data`.

It works then :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you had any other errors, but I found that removing `replace:true` made it work for me.

I'm not sure exactly what is happening here, but somehow the interaction of you adding the directive to the dom + replacing it immediately causes it not to work.

Another thing I noticed was that by using `$element.after(el);` you are ending up with an element that is OUTSIDE the controller's scope. It's not in the div that the controller has scope for. Unfortunately, I only saw this in MY plunkr, so don't know if this affected you also.

Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dt1Mr5?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm can you look at my plunkr? http://plnkr.co/edit/5Qnv6i8jhyRwMEWtRQO7?p=preview